# Xamarin, wait for async function ends

Tags: xamarin, async-await

In main file MainPage I have method OnAppearing contains two functions.

MainPage.cs

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            DataBaseService.checkNoteAlarmTimeActive();
            this.loadNotes();                       
            base.OnAppearing();
        }
```

Unfortunately method *loadNotes()* is fired before method *DataBaseService.checkNoteAlarmTimeActive();* ends. It makes some problem in my app. 
How to change it to *this.loadNotes()* wait to previous function ends job?

Thank you.
Class DataBaseService with metod:

```
public static async void checkNoteAlarmTimeActive()
        {           
            List<Note> notes = await getTimeActiveNotes();

            foreach(Note note in notes)
            {
                if(note.AlarmTime < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    note.AlarmTimeActive = false;
                    updateRecord(note);
                }
            }
        }
public static async Task<List<Note>> getTimeActiveNotes()
        {
            var notes = await _dbConnect.Table<Note>().Where(i => i.AlarmTimeActive == true).ToListAsync();            
            return notes;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you add async and await.

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            await DataBaseService.checkNoteAlarmTimeActive();
            this.loadNotes();                       
            base.OnAppearing();
        }
```

Comment: You would also need to change the method signature of checkNotAlarmTimeActive to "public static async **Task** checkNoteAlarmTimeActive()" in order to await it.

Comment: I can't make this method "OnAppearing()" async.

Comment: @Klick: Why not?

Comment: Sorry. I add "async" in wrong place. It works fine now thx. But is there other way to have it without make this function async. In ES6 there is nice "promises" system with function "then". Is there something similar in c#, xamarin?

Comment: Yep. .ContinueWith(...) which is exactly what an await creates behind the scenes.

Comment: Note, however, that both C# and JavaScript have moved to `async`/`await`, which results in cleaner code than promises/thenables.

Answer (score 2):

Your `CheckNoteAlarmTimeActive()`method returns void, therefore it cannot be awaited reliably (it is basically fire and forget).

You should always return `Task` instead.

The last thing to do is to add the `async` keyword to `OnApprearing`, so you can use `await` inside there (like Sean Sparkman said):

```
//C#
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    await DataBaseService.checkNoteAlarmTimeActive();
    this.loadNotes();                       
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

Just keep in mind: As `OnAppearing()` also returns void, it will return to the caller immediately after something is awaited in there (in this case your database call). So the rest of the lifecycle will continue and the rest of the method (after the `await`) will only happen after it finished.